Vue.js application(global build) is not working
I'm learning vue.js, everything worked fine but today vue decided that it won't work for no reason.
Vue devtool extension doesn't detect my code, dynamic content is not working and console throws error: Vue is not defined. I tried to solve this problem with some solutions that i found e.g.:
var Vue = require('vue'), import Vue from 'vue'  nothing worked.
Here is whole code:


<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vue podstawy</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">My Vue</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li v-for="link in links" class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">{{link.text}}</a>
                </li>
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="content" class="container">
        <h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
        <p>{{ content }}</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        Vue.createApp({
            data(){
                return{
                    links:[
                    {text:'Home',url:'home.html'},
                    {text:'About',url:'home.html'},
                    {text:'Contact',url:'home.html'}
                ]
                }
            }
        }).mount('nav');
        Vue.createApp({
            data(){
                return {
                    pageTitle: 'Hello Vue',
                    content: 'Welcome to wonderful world of Vue'
                };
            }
        }).mount('#content');

    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>



I didn't change any line of code and followed every step from a tutorial. Where is the problem?

Have you tried to load https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js in your browser and see what happens? Looks like unpkg.com has a problem. Do a closer look into your browsers console/network tab.

I loaded https://unpkg.com/vue@3 since whole link didn't work and it directed me to:  https://unpkg.com/vue@3.4.21/dist/vue.global.js , copy and paste that link and it now works. Thanks for help!

There was temporary outage with unpkg/cloudflare - https://github.com/vuejs/docs/issues/2794#issuecomment-2051797095 -- https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js should also work fine (without needing to pin the exact version)
